# no module named sys and time

Tags: python, import

I wrote a GUI, for which I used these imports:

```
import os

import sys

import serial

import scipy

import string

import time

import datetime

import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import matplotlib as mpl

from collections import deque

from numpy import array

from pylab import xlabel, ylabel, subplot

from scipy.fftpack import fft

from pylab import *
```

There is a red line below sys and time, I am using pycharm community edition 4.5.3, it is showing the reason for this error is '**no module named sys**' and same for time.
But when i tried to run it, it works perfectly.

What is the reason behind it and will it affect my code in future?

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10987834/importerror-no-module-named-cv2-when-running-django-project-from-pycharm-ide

Comment: Can you tell us if you resolved this, and, if so, how?

Comment: have you checked configuration - so python interpreter for the project is set properly?

Answer (score 3):

Change the python interpreter from python to python2.7. It's helped me.

Comment: How do you do that?

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html

Navigate to python2.7 instead of just python

Answer (score 0):

This is something I just ran into with Intellij 2017.3.4 where it could find every module except `sys` and `time` in the editor, but everything would run fine.  I had both 2.7 and 3.5 version of python and it did not seem to matter which one I selected as the SDK.  I tried adding and removing them.

When I went to Project Structure -> Platform Settings -> SDKs -> Python 3.5 -> Packages it prompted a warning that `Python packaging tools not found.` and had an install link.  I installed it and the editor no longer complained about sys and time.  When I switched SDKs to 2.7 (without installing the packaging tools) it complained again.

So I am not exactly sure what is happening that that seemed to fix it for me it other people run into this problem.