# Running OpenCV from a Python virtualenv

Tags: python, opencv, virtualenv

I'm trying to install OpenCV within a virtualenv on my Ubuntu Server 12.04. I found [a thread discussing this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9592389/is-it-possible-to-run-opencv-python-binding-from-a-virtualenv) but managed to extract no information from it.

I tried using `pip install pyopencv` but it failed.

```
...
package/extras/core/ndarray.cpp:598:1:   instantiated from here

package/extras/core/ndarray.cpp:546:9: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 4 has type ‘Py_intptr_t {aka long int}’ [-Wformat]

package/extras/core/ndarray.cpp: In function ‘boost::python::api::object sdcpp::from_ndarray_impl(const sdcpp::ndarray&) [with T = cv::Scalar_<double>]’:

package/extras/core/ndarray.cpp:601:1:   instantiated from here

package/extras/core/ndarray.cpp:546:9: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 4 has type ‘Py_intptr_t {aka long int}’ [-Wformat]

package/extras/core/ndarray.cpp: In function ‘boost::python::api::object sdcpp::from_ndarray_impl(const sdcpp::ndarray&) [with T = cv::Range]’:

package/extras/core/ndarray.cpp:604:1:   instantiated from here

package/extras/core/ndarray.cpp:546:9: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 4 has type ‘Py_intptr_t {aka long int}’ [-Wformat]

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

This error only occurs the second time I run `pip install`. If I delete the remainging `build/` folder I get this error.

```
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

Configuring PyOpenCV via CMake...

Error: error occurred while running CMake to configure PyOpenCV.

You may want to manually configure PyOpenCV by running cmake's tools:

    mkdir build

    cd build

    cmake-gui ..    OR    cmake ..

    cd ..

----------------------------------------
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 255
```

I have at least the following apt packages installed.

```
build-essential
uuid-dev
python-dev
python-pip
libpq-dev
cmake
libboost-dev
libcv-dev
libcvaux-dev
libboost-python-dev
libboost1.48-dev
```

How can I install OpenCV within my virtualenv?

Comment: I'm experiencing this same issue. I noticed, though, that 'pyopencv' corresponds to this project http://code.google.com/p/pyopencv/ and not the python bindings that come with opencv 2.X

Answer (score 13):

Fired up a virtualenv and followed this guide: http://www.samontab.com/web/2011/06/installing-opencv-2-2-in-ubuntu-11-04/ , up until manipulating and copying the cv shared objects.  Instead, I copied cv.so (from my OpenCV-2.2.0/lib directory) to my virtualenv site-packages (eg. env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/).  Once cv.so was in my environment, I was able to import cv within python.

Comment: Thanks, copying the shared objects was what I was missing! Only difference was I copied cv.py[c] and cv2.so from /usr/lib/pymodules, analagous to https://github.com/ingenuitas/SimpleCV#installation

Answer (score 9):

Here is the cleanest way, using pyenv and the virtualenv plug-in.

Install Python with shared library support (so we get a libpython2.7.dylib on Mac OS X or libpython2.7.so on Linux).

```
env PYTHON_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--enable-shared" pyenv install -v 2.7.6
```

Create the virtualenv, based on the version of python we just installed.

```
pyenv virtualenv 2.7.6 myvirtualenv
```

Activate the virtualenv.

```
pyenv shell myvirtualenv
pyenv rehash
```

Install numpy. Otherwise opencv will fail to link itself to Python correctly.

```
pip install numpy
```

Set the prefix of the python install.

```
PREFIX_MAIN=`pyenv virtualenv-prefix`
```

Set the prefix of the environment. (sic! The name of these pyenv commands are a bit deceptive!)

```
PREFIX=`pyenv prefix`
```

Now configure and install opencv. Notice that the opencv binaries and packages will be installed in our virtualenv while the dynamic library and includes of the Python install is used.

```
cd openCV2.4
mkdir release
cd release
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="$PREFIX" -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE="$PREFIX"/bin/python2.7 -DPYTHON_LIBRARY="$PREFIX_MAIN"/lib/libpython2.7.so -DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR="$PREFIX_MAIN"/include/python2.7 -DPYTHON_PACKAGES_PATH="$PREFIX"/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ ..
make install
```

(On OSX, replace libpython2.7.so with libpython2.7.dylib.)

Answer (score 0):

Did you already `apt-get build-dep python-opencv`? This will install all the required dependencies to build it from source; which you need if you are trying to install it in a virtual environment.

Comment: I have all this opencv.i386 : Collection of algorithms for computer vision
opencv-devel.i386 : Development files for using the OpenCV library
opencv-python.i386 : Python bindings for apps which use OpenCV
I use Fedora , the error is:"/include/c++/4.3.2/bits/stl_move.h:87: error: within this context" I using virtualenv.py .

Comment: @CatalinFestila you should open another discussion as your question is different than what this is talking about.