# openCV Configuring incomplete, errors occurred

Tags: python, opencv, python-2.7

I'm trying to install Python [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Mac_OS_X_OpenCV_Port) being new to Python I got the error below and need to know what it means (and maybe how to solve)?

I installed like this (Mac running python 2.7 in virtualenv).

```
sudo port selfupdate
sudo port install opencv
sudo port -v install opencv +python27
```

Then:

```
sudo pip install pyopencv
```

... and I got this error:

```
Error:

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

Configuring PyOpenCV via CMake...

Error: error occurred while running CMake to configure PyOpenCV.

You may want to manually configure PyOpenCV by running cmake's tools:

    mkdir build

    cd build

    cmake-gui ..    OR    cmake ..

    cd ..
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11184847/running-opencv-from-a-python-virtualenv

Comment: @user1929959 does not help answer relates to Ubuntu

Comment: What do you need pyopencv for? Why not just use the bindings that you installed with MacPorts?

Comment: @w.m could you explain?

Comment: With 'sudo port install opencv +python27' you installed the Python bindings, just 'import cv2' in the MacPorts Python2.7.

Comment: In my Python app I tired import cv and got not found

Comment: Maybe you are using the Apple-Python? The modules will be installed for the MacPorts Python. Type 'which python', if it is not the one in /opt/local/bin, change this with port select python

Comment: "which python" states it's loading from my virtualenv directory @ /env/bin/python

Comment: Ah. Well if you have to use virtualenv I can't help you either, just try to go with the Ubuntu tutorial as best you can. And maybe ask yourself whether you really need the virtualenv though.