# virtualenv to use --system-site-packages, but only for specific packages?

Tags: python, opencv, virtualenv

In a perfect world, I'd like to use pip inside a `--no-site-packages` virtualenv.

However: OpenCV. From what I've read so far it sounds tricky to reliably install OpenCV in a virtualenv, so I've accepted having to install that as a system package for now (target platform is Ubuntu, so I'm installing `python-opencv` with apt). I'd like to install everything else with pip into my virtualenv, though.

To make OpenCV available to my application, I've initialized the virtualenv with  `--system-site-packages`.

When installing other dependencies with `env/bin/pip install -U -r requirements.txt` now, some of the requirements (which happen to be dependencies of OpenCV) are seen as satisfied. Not surprising, but also not what I want.

Is there a sane way to make **only** OpenCV available from site-packages, and have everything thing else loaded from, and installed to, the virtualenv?

Comment: Checkout the below link:  
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11184847/running-opencv-from-a-python-virtualenv?rq=1)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 2018, you can easily install recent versions of OpenCV in a virtualenv using the [opencv-python](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/) package.

Answer (score 0):

I have already installed OpenCV but in order to use that installation in my virtual environment I followed the following steps

- Find your directory for system site-packages. You may refer to [@peterino's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46071447)
- Follow these steps:

---

```
# This is the path for my system-site-packages
$ cd /home/aadi/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
$ ls | grep cv`
# Here if you have open cv installed you'll find the result. For me, it was something like this
#I am attaching an image of my result'
```

[Result (Image) from my end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zW4zu.png)

```
# Then I copied both of the cv2 files i.e cv2 and opencv_python-3.4.0.12.dist-info to my virtual env site-packages.

$ cp -r opencv_python-3.4.0.12.dist-info /home/aadi/prog/python_apps/venv/lib/python3.6/site-package && cp -r cv2 /home/aadi/prog/python_apps/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages
```

Here python_apps is the directory where I've created my virtual environment
After then I reactivated my virtual environment and bingo! importing cv2 doesn't give any error

```
(venv) ➜  python_apps python
Python 3.6.5 (default, Apr  1 2018, 05:46:30) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
>>>
```