# Compiling OpenCV3 with pyenv using python 3.5.0 on OSX

Tags: python-3.x, opencv3.0

Took me a while to figure this out so I thought I'd write it down.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Install python with shared library support through pyenv:

```
env PYTHON_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--enable-shared" pyenv install 3.5.0
```

Make a new virtualenv named opencv

```
pyenv virtualenv 3.5.0 opencv
```

Activate the virtualenv and install numpy

```
pyenv activate opencv
pyenv rehash
pip install numpy
```

Clone opencv and opencv_contrib and put it in ~/

```
cd ~
git clone https://github.com/Itseez/opencv.git
cd opencv
git checkout 3.1.0

cd ~
git clone https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib
cd opencv_contrib
git checkout 3.1.0

cd ~/opencv
mkdir build
cd build
```

Run CMake and install

```
PREFIX_MAIN=`pyenv virtualenv-prefix`
PREFIX=`pyenv prefix`
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
    -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="$PREFIX" \
    -D PYTHON3_EXECUTABLE="$PREFIX"/bin/python3.5 \
    -D PYTHON3_PACKAGES_PATH="$PREFIX"/lib/python3.5/site-packages \
    -D PYTHON3_LIBRARY="$PREFIX_MAIN"/lib/libpython3.5m.dylib \
    -D PYTHON3_INCLUDE_DIR="$PREFIX_MAIN"/include/python3.5m \
    -D PYTHON3_NUMPY_INCLUDE_DIRS="$PREFIX"/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/include \
    -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF \
    -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON \
    -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON \
    -D BUILD_opencv_python3=ON \
    -D INSTALL_NAME_DIR=${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib \
    -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_contrib/modules ..

make -j8

make install
```

Note: if you are using python 3.5.2 you need to change

```
PYTHON3_EXECUTABLE="$PREFIX"/bin/python3
PYTHON3_LIBRARY="$PREFIX_MAIN"/lib/libpython3.5m.a
```

source: basically mashed these guides together:

- http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/29/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-3-4-on-osx/
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/24112175/1591757
- http://answers.opencv.org/question/4134/cmake-install_name_tool-absolute-path-for-library-on-mac-osx/

Comment: I needed to add `-D BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF` because the `cv2.so` binary it made couldn't find my dylibs(?), and I also followed the update on your first site saying that OpenCV 3.1.0 is broken unless you switch to `-D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF` (didn't bother trying with it ON)

Comment: I got this error with I run `make - j8`: `fatal error: 'opencv2/core/hal/intrin.hpp' file not found` . Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: @NickT Thanks, I've updated the answer for 3.1.0. Not sure what the deal is with BUILD_SHARED_LIBS though.

Comment: @sooon Try checking out 3.1.0 for both repos and building again.

Comment: I'd use just a single prefix of the virtual environment. Mixing different Pythons calls for problems... Also, it's enough to set the CMake flag -DPython3_ROOT_DIR="$(pyenv prefix)", it will set the other flags accordingly.