# Pycharm gives an import error

Tags: python, opencv, pycharm

I have installed opencv by following the instruction [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10145537/4127806). my code that imports opencv works fine when I run it from terminal. However, when I run my code from pycharm I get:

```
ImportError: No module named cv2
```

I have set the python interpreter to my desired virtual environment in Pycharm.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15790501/why-cv2-so-missing-after-opencv-installed

Answer (score 0):

**Background** : OP is using `SPE Stani's python editor`. OP has installed OpenCV `/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` which is not detected by the above mentioned editor. Adding this path to PYTHONPATH doesn't solve the issue.

**Solution (any one of the below):**

1. Add this path to `sys.path` and put it in every file.

`import sys
 sys.path.append('/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages')`

2. Copy `cv2.so` file to any directory in the `sys.path`.

This may help you.